# [SOLVED] How do we transmit trajectories to our ABB IRB 140 using the ABB Package

Tags: ros, abb, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have the ABB driver communicating with ROS, but we are having difficulties issuing commands to the robot.

So far we haven't been able to find any documentation on how to send trajectories to the robot, so we have been going through all of the code to try and understand it better.
It seems like the ABB driver is a complete solution, however; we haven't been able to find which node we are able to send trajectories from.
We would like to use a planned path from Moveit (Rviz) to create our trajectory and then send that trajectory to the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199400/%5Bsolved%5D-how-do-we-transmit-trajectories-to-our-abb-irb-140-using-the-abb-package/) by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-12**:
It would help if you could tells us what 'having difficulties' means exactly. What are you trying to do, and what isn't working? What do you think should happen?

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2014-12-15**:
Sorry for the vague question on Friday, it was a long day of learning and research. I added more information to the question up above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Provided that you are using the [ABB driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb) from the ROS-Industrial community, you can find the topics it publishes and subscribes to on the [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver#Nodes) page.

Most users will want to interact with the `joint_trajectory_action` node. It accepts msgs of the type `control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal` on the `joint_trajectory_action/goal` topic (similar to other action servers controlling arm motion).

The `joint_trajectory_action` node then translates these msgs into suitable `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory` msgs for the  `/joint_path_command` topic, to which the specific driver nodes subscribe. In this case the `motion_download_interface` from the `abb_driver` package.

> We would like to use a planned path from Moveit (Rviz) to create our trajectory and then send that trajectory to the robot.

The ROS-Industrial drivers all implement the basic (standardised) ROS interface for arm control that lets MoveIt (or one of it's controllers) interact with them. Controlling a ROS-Industrial driver (or the arm connected to it) is no different from working with any other ROS driver implementing the same interface.

There isn't yet a support package or MoveIt configuration package for the IRB140, but they aren't too difficult to create. See [wiki.ros.org/abb](http://wiki.ros.org/abb) for some existing packages, the [Create a URDF for an Industrial Robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create%20a%20URDF%20for%20an%20Industrial%20Robot) tutorial for some pointers on how to create a proper URDF, and the [Create a MoveIt Package for an Industrial Robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot) tutorial for ROS-Industrial compatible MoveIt configuration packages.

You might also be interested in the [ROS-Industrial training exercises](http://ros-industrial.github.io/industrial_training). They take you through the process of setting up and interacting with some (simulated) industrial robots, and also planning and execution motions with them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2014-12-15**:
Thanks for the fast reply! We did have success just about 15 minutes ago transmitting a trajectory, and having the robot execute that trajectory.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-15**:
Issues solved then?

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2014-12-16**:
I think so, we still have a ways to go on this project but this was a great first step. We were able to use the cartesian path planner to plan a path, and we were able to develop a simple publisher to publish the trajectory to the joint path command topic.

**Comment by [jaam002](https://answers.ros.org/users/23513/jaam002/) on 2015-10-05**:
Hi @DHCustomPak , I'm currently working with an IRB140 and i have succesfully implemented the path planning with RVIZ and MOVEIT. However, I'm having problems with the joint_3;I mean, the IRB execute the path, but the joint_3 some times set in a wrong direction. Did you have a similar problem?